# ListDirectoryPeople not showing names for most contacts?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

When I navigate over to contacts.google.com then to 'Directory' tab. I see all emails and fullnames of people from my Gsuite organization. However, when I used this api: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople It can only show things like email addresses, but not name. Is this a bug or did I miss something? Let me know if the question is vague or I need to provide more details.

Comment: Hey @Mercado! Same to me. Did you find any solution?